# proper way to call http (RESTFUL WebAPI) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, callback

I have following controller code

```
module.registerController('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {
        myFactory.get(function (data) {
            console.log(data); /// data is always undefined 
        });
    });
```

and following the factory which is calling restful webapi

```
module.registerFactory('myFactory', ['$http',
    function ($http) {
            function get(callback) {
                $http.get('mywebapiurl')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        //debugger; data comes back from server
                        callback(response);
                    }).error(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
            }

        return {
            get: get
        }
    }]);
```

The factory is calling webapi service and does gets the data back. However in controller the data doesnt get returned.

Am I missing something obvious here? Also not sure if this is the best way to call webservice in angularjs in controller using factory. Any inputs are most welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: try myFactory.get().then(function(data){ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead of passing a callback. As `$http.get` already returns a promise, you can just return that, or a derived promise that returns the response data directly. By the way, your `factory` looks like it should be a `service` instead:

```
angular.moudule('yourApp')
.service('myService', ['$http', myService]);

function myService($http) {
    this.get = function(url) {
        return $http.get(url)
                   .then(function transformData(response){
                       return response.data;
                   }).catch(function onError(rejectionResponse){
                       //Whatever you want to do here
                   });
    }
}
```

This way `myService.get` will return a promise you can `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` on what you want, staying in the frameworks coding style. For example:

```
var squirrels = [];
myService.get('http://squirrelshop.com/api/squirrels')
    .then(function(squirrelsData){
        console.log('Got the squirrels!');

        squirrels = squirrelsData;
    }).catch(function(rejection){
        console.warn('Couldnt fetch squirrels. Reason: ' + rejection);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks the promise does seems a better way of doing this. Could you please post a sample code with using promise. I was also a bit uneasy about using callback. thanks

Comment: @activebiz I did. I recommend to do some research on promises and their syntax, theyre quite elegant, but explaining how exactly all off this works would be a bit too broad for an SO answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

controller code

```
module.registerController('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {
    myFactory.get("url").then(function(d) {
            console.log(d.data); 
        }
    });
});
```

factory which is calling restful webapi

```
module.registerFactory('myFactory', ['$http',
function ($http) {
         var apiFactory = {
               get:function(url){
                   return $http.get(url);
               }
         }
    return apiFactory;
}]);
```

Success and failure in factory

```
module.registerFactory('myFactory', ['$http',
function ($http) {
     var apiFactory = {
           get:function(url){
               return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
                      // success
                      return responce.data;
               },function(error){
                      //failure
                      return error;
               };
           }
     }
    return apiFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the success and failure code in factory?

Comment: Yes, its possible, let me add this in my answer.